# Why do function objects evaluate to True in python?

Tags: python, function, function-pointers

In python it is valid to make a construction like:

```
def a(): 
    return 0

if a: 
    print "Function object was considered True"
else:  
    print "Function object was considered False"
```

I wish to ask what is the logic that a function pointer is evaluated to True.

Why was this kind of construction inserted in the language?

Comment: Can you post more context? Is `a` defined anywhere else?

Comment: This page goes into some reasons you may want to use this feature: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/boolean.html

Comment: the same as any programing language... anything that does not evaluate to false will evaluate to true ... the things that evaluate to false are much easier to enumerate (0,False,None,[],"",etc)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A lot of things evaluate to `True` in Python. From the [documentation on Boolean operators](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true.

Functions in Python, like so many things, are *objects*, and not empty. Thus, in a boolean context, they evaluate to True.

Comment: @MagnusHoff: Thanks for the correction; had not noticed the hash fragment was lost, it was certainly my intention to include that.

Answer (score 3):

The rules for evaluating "truthiness" are in the Python documentation chapter on [Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Note in particular that

> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are
>   always true.

In conclusion; function objects are always true.

Answer (score 2):

A list of objects that are False in python:

- `None`
- `[]`
- `{}`
- `empty set`
- `empty frozenset`
- `False`
- `0`
- `0.0`
- `0L`
- `0j`
- empty `defaultdict`
- `Classes` that have implemented `__nonzero__()` method and that returns a falsy value
   otherwise `__len__()` is called. In python 3x `__bool__()` replaced `__nonzero__()`.

Comment: And 0.0. And 0j. And 0L. Or has length 0, or it's `__nonzero__()` method returns False.

Comment: You should add `__len__()` as it is evaluated when there is no `__nonzero__()` defined. Also note that `__bool__()` replaces `__nonzero__()` for Python 3.x

Answer (score 2):

In the Truth Value Testing that @Magnus Hoff linked to, I found the most instructive statement to be:

> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a _*bool*_() method that returns False or a _*len*_() method that returns zero, when called with the object.

I tried defining my own classes, and it seems like _*bool*_() takes priority over _*len*_(), which makes sense:

```
class Falsish(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = "False, even though len(self) > 0"
    def __bool__(self):
        return False
    def __len__(self):
        return 2

class StillFalsish(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = "False, even though len(self) > 0"
    def __len__(self):
        return 2
    def __bool__(self):
        return False

class Truish(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = "True, even though len(self) = 0"
    def __bool__(self):
        return True
    def __len__(self):
        return 0

class StillTruish(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = "True, even though len(self) = 0"
    def __len__(self):
        return 0
    def __bool__(self):
        return True

class NowFalsish(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = "False, with no __bool__(), since len(self) = 0"
    def __len__(self):
        return 0

class NowTruish(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = "True, with no __bool__(), since len(self) > 0"
    def __len__(self):
        return 2

class EvenThisIsTruish(object):
    pass


mybool1 = Falsish()
mybool2 = StillFalsish()
mybool3 = Truish()
mybool4 = StillTruish()
mybool5 = NowFalsish()
mybool6 = NowTruish()
mybool7 = EvenThisIsTruish()
if mybool1: print("mybool1 is true")
if mybool2: print("mybool2 is true")
if mybool3: print("mybool3 is true")
if mybool4: print("mybool4 is true")
if mybool5: print("mybool5 is true")
if mybool6: print("mybool6 is true")
if mybool7: print("mybool7 is true")
```

The output of the above code is:

```
mybool3 is true
mybool4 is true
mybool6 is true
mybool7 is true
```