# Why does "if foo:" follow the branch even if the function foo returns False?

Tags: python

```
def foo(a):
    print("I'm foo")
    return False


if foo:
    print("OK")
else:
    print("KO")
```

I run it and it returns OK. I know, I should have written `if foo():`.

I often forget parenthesis when calling functions without parameters and I need an explaination about the result.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: `foo` is a function, you are not calling it with `()`. a function is always true, because it's not `None`

Comment: If you create a function without parameters, you do not need to have a parameter `a`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697338/why-do-function-objects-evaluate-to-true-in-python

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
 if foo:
    print("OK")
else:
    print("KO")
```

you are actually testing if the function pointer `foo`. It is defined, so it prints "OK" and it does not call the function. With the parenthesis, you call the `foo` function and runs its code.

Comment: But if it undefined, it should raises an exception, shoudn't it?

Comment: @vincent-bv Yes indeed. This is not a good mean to test if foo is defined since it can only return True or raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

python `if` condition statisfies if the value is not equal to any of these

```
0, None, "", [], {}, False, ()
```

Here

```
def foo(a):
    print("I'm foo")
    return False

>>>foo
<function __main__.foo>
```

That means variable `foo` pointing to the function.If you call your function `foo(arg)` then it will return `False` as you expecting.So

```
>>>foo("arg")
False
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case your code is same as

```
if foo != None:
    print("OK")
else:
    print("KO")
```

Result is

> "OK"

because `foo` actually exists.