# Code using a variable like a function/method with ()?

Tags: python, callback, event-listener

I am looking at an existing code base that is using a bool variable like a method, for example:

```
class Manager(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._on_elect_callback = None
        self._on_revoke_callback = None
        self.... = ... (..., event_listener = self._event)

    def _event(self, type):
        on_elect_callback = self._on_elect_callback
        if type == SOME_CONSTANT:
            ....
            if on_elect_callback:
                on_elect_callback()

    def do_this(self, on_elect_function):
        self._on_elect_callback = on_elect_function
        if self....:
            on_elect_function()
```

Questions:

1. I am curious how that `on_elect_callback` is being used like a function with `()` after `if` condition on the last line. Isn't that some boolean variable? I searched the repo and there is no definition for that. What is it doing?
2. Also, I would like to set a variable in `__init__` that the callback function of event can use like "hey this event type IS SOME_CONSTANT, so set the variable in `__init__` to `"ABCD"` (or `True`), how can I achieve it? Is the way in the code above the way to do it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697338/why-do-function-objects-evaluate-to-true-in-python

Comment: `self._on_elect_callback` is set to `None` initially, which is considered **falsy**, but presumably there muse be another method somewhere which assigns some sort of callable, which is considered **truthy** and will pass the `if`.

Comment: @quamrana yes! there is a function like def do_this(self, on_elect_fn): self_on_elect_cb  on_elect_function. And even in this def it does the same thing, on_elect_function(). So at this point I am not sure if these on_elect_callback and on_elect_function are being used as bool variables or some other type, and if they're variables or functions... I'm so confused.

Comment: Please include this method in the question above. Also please see my comment and the link that @JustinEzequiel posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `self._on_elect_callback` was probably going to be assigned a function as in `self._on_elect_callback = lambda: "I'm a function"`. I think the reason you think it was meant to be a variable is because it is used in an if expression. The reason is that if `self._on_elect_callback` gets assigned a function the expression will evaluate to `True`, as functions support a method `bool`, which returns `True` by default.
About Q2, sure you can, functions are objects in python, so you can pass them around to higher order functions, or assign them as variables as in the example

```
class Manager(object):

    def __init__(self, function):
        self._on_elect_callback = function # here we assigned the given function
        if not function: 
            # here we define a default attribute using an anonymous function
            self._on_elect_callback = lambda: "Default Function"

    def _event(self, type):
        if self._on_elect_callback:
            self._on_elect_callback()
```

Comment: Can you update your code snippet with proper formatting. Plus can you fix the `_event()` method so that it uses `self._on_elect_callback`